# flash as3 - I need binary search in byteArray data

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, search, binary, arrays

I have a problem with getting parts of the `ByteArray` data.
There is a binary text in `fileData`:

```
var fileData:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
//..........here's code that fills this var with binary data
.....readBytes(fileData,0,1000);
//
```

Data is like this:

```
йYЯyeSВ–нkq(г<<<start>>>:xЪмЅdf”cйxЪsdfмЅ”cйdxЪмЅ”cй<<<end>>>В–нkВ
```

So, I need to find position of `<<< start >>>` and `<<< end >>>` and copy data, that is between them.

But searching `fileData.toString().indexOf('<<< start >>>')` sometimes gets wrong position of this string, and sometimes can't find it at all.

What can I do to correctly determine the position of part of the data that I need?

Comment: Try tracing `fileData` or `fileData.toString()` and see what it returns. It might also help if you show more code, such as how you're populating `fileData`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not use `fileData.toString().indexOf()` since you are working with binary data. You have to search a sequence of bytes.

The following function retrieve the position of a specified pattern:

```
public function indexOf(bytes:ByteArray, search:String, startOffset:uint = 0):void
{
    if (bytes == null || bytes.length == 0) {
        throw new ArgumentError("bytes parameter should not be null or empty");
    }

    if (search == null || search.length == 0) {
        throw new ArgumentError("search parameter should not be null or empty");
    }

    // Fast return is the search pattern length is shorter than the bytes one
    if (bytes.length < startOffset + search.length) {
        return -1;
    }

    // Create the pattern
    var pattern:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    pattern.writeUTFBytes(search);

    // Initialize loop variables
    var end:Boolean;
    var found:Boolean;
    var i:uint = startOffset;
    var j:uint = 0;
    var p:uint = pattern.length;
    var n:uint = bytes.length - p;

    // Repeat util end
    do {
        // Compare the current byte with the first one of the pattern
        if (bytes[i] == pattern[0]) {
            found = true;
            j = p;

            // Loop through every byte of the pattern
            while (--j) {
                if (bytes[i + j] != pattern[j]) {
                    found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }

            // Return the pattern position
            if (found) {
                return i;
            }
        }

        // Check if end is reach
        end = (++i > n);
    } while (!end);

    // Pattern not found
    return -1;
}
```

Then you can use the function this way:

```
var extractedBytes = new ByteArray();
var startPos:int = indexOf(fileData, "<<<start>>>");
var endPos:int;

if (startPos == -1) {
    trace("<<<start>>> not found");
} else {
    endPos = indexOf(fileData, "<<<end>>>", startPos + 11); // "<<<start>>>".length = 11
}

if (startPos == -1) {
    trace("<<<end>>> not found");
} else {
    // Extract the bytes between <<<start>>> and <<<end>>>
    fileData.readBytes(extractedBytes, startPos + 11, endPos);
}
```

**Disclaimer:** I haven't tested my code!

Comment: I don't cover all cases. The idea was to demonstrate how to do.

Comment: anyway, thanx.It seems the only way

Answer (score 5):

Just a tad different approach:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class ByteArraySearch extends Sprite
    {
        public function ByteArraySearch()
        {
            super();
            this.test();
        }

        private function test():void
        {
            var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var start:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var end:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var subseq:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            var startPosition:int;
            var endPosition:int;

            bytes.writeUTFBytes("йYЯyeSВ–нkq(г<<<start>>>:xЪмЅdf”cйxЪsdfмЅ”cйdxЪмЅ”cй<<<end>>>В–нkВ");
            start.writeUTFBytes("<<<start>>>");
            end.writeUTFBytes("<<<end>>>");
            startPosition = this.searchBytes(start, bytes);
            endPosition = this.searchBytes(end, bytes);

            subseq.writeBytes(bytes, startPosition + start.length, 
                endPosition - startPosition - start.length);
            trace(startPosition, endPosition, subseq);
        }

        private function searchBytes(needle:ByteArray, heystack:ByteArray):int
        {
            var position:int;
            var trackback:int;
            var searcheable:int;
            var head:int;
            var readNeedle:Boolean;
            var hasTrackBack:Boolean;
            var needlePosition:int;
            var current:int;

            if (!needle || !needle.length || !heystack || !heystack.length ||
                needle.length > heystack.length)
                return -1;
            searcheable = heystack.length - needle.length;
            head = needle[0];

            for (; position < searcheable; position++)
            {
                current = heystack[position];
                // first state - we didn't yet find the first matching byte
                if (!readNeedle)
                {
                    // if this is the first mathing byte
                    if (readNeedle = current == head)
                    {
                        // then set both the trackback and position in the 
                        // needle to the first byte in the needle, as this
                        // is what will be checked next
                        trackback = needlePosition = 1;
                        // we don't know yet if the first (or any later) byte
                        // can be tracked back to in our search, false by default
                        hasTrackBack = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // we found the match
                    if (needlePosition == needle.length)
                    {
                        position -= needlePosition;
                        break;
                    }
                    // if we haven't yet found a position to track back to
                    // and the current byte is the same as the first byte in the 
                    // needle, then this is the trackback position.
                    if (!hasTrackBack && current == head)
                        hasTrackBack = true;
                    if (needle[needlePosition] == current)
                    {
                        // advance the position in the needle and the trackback, 
                        // if we didn't find any point to track back to
                        needlePosition++;
                        if (!hasTrackBack) trackback = needlePosition;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        // since the current byte didn't match, reset the position to
                        // the first trackback point that we found.
                        readNeedle = false;
                        position = position - needlePosition + trackback;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (position == searcheable) position = -1;
            return position;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems a bit cleaner in my opinion, or at least more organised. In any case I'd personally use this myself.