# Is there a simple method to match an array of bytes in an byte array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to check for a sequence of bytes in a byte array. Is there a method in the [ByteArray](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html) [class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7d54.html) that works like `indexOf()`?

For example,

I'm trying to find out if a file is a [PNG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header) or JPG and so I want to check the byte array for that sequence of characters.

```
var PNG_INFO:Array = [89,50,4E,47];
var byteArray:ByteArray = new ByteArray();

var position:int = byteArray.indexOf(PNG_INFO);
var value:String = byteArray.readBytes(position, PNG_INFO.length);

if (value =="PNG") { trace("is png") }
```

I don't know if the code above is correct but *I keep running into this problem where I have to find an array of bytes in a byte array*. So my question is is there a method for what I'm looking for?

More info on the PNG Header array of hexadecimal characters [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header).

**Update:**
I've just now thought that I wish I could use a RegEx to find what I'm looking for like this:

```
// dream code - find the value between those characters 
var data:Object = byteArray.exec(/89,50,4E,47(.*?)0xF0,0xF1/);
```

Of course, it is only a dream. It would be too easy if RegEx was supported in ByteArrays.

According to Nick's answer I need to:

> ...loop the byte array, grab each byte and if there's a match keep
>   comparing until I either find the full match or the end of the file?

*Is there a method that does this part for me? That's what I'm wondering. It seems like something you'd have to do quite often so maybe there are functions. I can post what I've written so far if that's the case.*

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but couldn't that sequence of bytes coincidentally show up in any number of other data types besides a PNG? Forgive me if this is a dumb question. I'm just thinking of how a series of bytes can be read out as an image or a sound or an integer or a string or whatever.

Comment: Yeah, Neal's right, you don't want to scan the whole file for the sequence you're looking for; you could find the png header sequence in the jpg and visa versa.

Comment: They could but the list of file formats I'm working with provide a few safe guards. For PNG the sequence will be in the first 4 bytes. For JPEG there is a marker for "JFIF" that is somewhere further on. 

I won't have to deal with every file type. So how would you do it if you had to find a sequence of bytes?

Comment: For jpg I don't think it's 'somewhere further on', I think JFIF is always starting at byte 6

Comment: @1.21gigawatts confirm: are your bytes always for a complete image only? ie: no extra bytes to ignore until actual wanted image bytes are found...

Comment: @VC.One From what I've read jpg can have thumbnails. ATM I only need to know if the file is png or jpg. Later I may need to know if a file is a gif or swf but that's about it for now. I don't want to read the whole file of course. With JPEG there is start of frame and that contains size information but you have to loop through the app sections to get past any thumbnail data. But size is a different story. So, the answer is no I don't think so. I don't know what any other extra bytes there would be. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes it does... For example, sometimes a jpeg can be embedded within mp3 bytes as album art so wanted to know if you have to skip anything to find the image header. I'll assume you don't and show you how to check bytes for format signatures

Comment: Possible duplicate of [flash as3 - I need binary search in byteArray data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11777348/flash-as3-i-need-binary-search-in-bytearray-data)

Comment: @1.21gigawatts ...If i I say _"I will show you..."_ don't feel shy to ask for a progress report later on. I'm currenty working with bytes and remembered your Question. See if my Answer helps your project(s) in some way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this example helps you. The idea is to find a candidate byte and then check if following bytes makes up rest-of-search item. So for bytes `CA FE BA BE` we search only for byte `0xCA` and whenever one (out of many) is found we then check if it's followed by bytes `0xFE`+`0xBA`+`0xBE`...

Here's a complete program to study...

The main function you want is :

```
indexOfBytes (byteArray:ByteArray, value:String, startPosition:int = 0, endPosition:int = 0, endian:String = null):int
```

Which returns an `int` of the offset of search sequence's beginning. I've thrown in a `checkImageFormat( bytes );` function where `bytes` are either **.jpg** or **.png** bytes. This will return a `String` saying whether if "jpg" or "png".

```
package  
{

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.utils.ByteArray;
import flash.utils.*;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
import flash.events.*;
import flash.net.URLStream;


public class Check_Bytes_Image_v1 extends MovieClip 
{
    public var bytes    :ByteArray = new ByteArray();
    public var stream   :URLStream = new URLStream();
    public var loader   :Loader = new Loader();

    public var formatFound : Boolean = false;
    public var str_Format : String = "";
    public var str_Search : String = "";
    public var tempStr : String = "";
    public var tempUInt : uint = 0;
    public var bytePos : int = 0;

    public var searchString:String = "";;
    public var searchArray:Array = new Array();

    public function Check_Bytes_Image_v1() 
    {
        //# add canvas
        addChild(loader);

        //# load image bytes via URLStream
        stream.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onStreamProgress);
        stream.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
        stream.load(new URLRequest("image1.png")); //image1.png
    }

    public function onStreamProgress(evt:ProgressEvent):void
    { evt.target.readBytes(bytes, bytes.length, evt.target.bytesAvailable); }

    public function completeHandler(evt:Event):void 
    {

        //bytes_toString(bytes); //if you want to check hex output

        //# update a string with format type
        str_Format = checkImageFormat( bytes );
        trace("Image format is  : " + str_Format );

        searchString = "89 50 4E 47"; //use any known sequential bytes in your Array
        bytePos = indexOfBytes( bytes, searchString );
        trace("bytes begin at : " + bytePos);

        bytes.position = 0; //reset to starting pos
        loader.loadBytes(bytes); //decode & display image
        trace("loaded image now...");
        //bytes.clear(); //empty the bytes
    }

    //# findBytes (byteArray:ByteArray, value:String, startPosition:int = 0, endPosition:int = 0, endian:String = null):int
    public function indexOfBytes (byteArray:ByteArray, value:String, startPosition:int = 0, endPosition:int = 0, endian:String = null):int
    {
        str_Search = value;
        trace("str_Search v1 is " + str_Search);

        //# Clean up possible hex notation
        str_Search = str_Search.split("0x").join("");
        str_Search = str_Search.split(".").join("");
        str_Search = str_Search.split("/").join("");

        //# Clean up hex (remove non Alpha-Numeric, white spaces, new line, etc)
        str_Search = str_Search.replace(/\W+/g, ""); //# clear all non Alpha-Numeric chars
        str_Search.toUpperCase(); //# convert to uppercase
        trace("str_Search v2 is " + str_Search);

        tempUInt = 0; searchArray = []; //# resets

        //# convert input string into two-digits-per-slot array
        while ( tempUInt < str_Search.length) 
        {
            searchArray.push(str_Search.substring(tempUInt, Math.min(tempUInt+2, str_Search.length) ) );
            tempUInt += 2;
        }

        trace("searchArray length is : " + searchArray.length);

        //# search bytes for same hex vlues

        //# Resets for WHILE loop
        if ( startPosition != 0) { bytePos = startPosition; }
        else { bytePos = 0; }

        tempUInt = 0;

        while (byteArray.bytesAvailable)
        {
            //# safety check :  Stop at limit of bytes range
            if ( endPosition != 0 ) //# Don't go over end pos if not null
            {   
                if ( byteArray.position >= endPosition )
                { 
                    trace("reached end position of search : stopping at: " + byteArray.position );
                    break;
                }
            }
            else //# Don't go over total bytes length
            {
                if ( byteArray.position > (byteArray.length - searchArray.length) )
                { 
                    trace("reached ENDing bytes of search : stopping at: " + byteArray.position );
                    break;
                }
            } //# end safety check...

            //# Find search values
            byteArray.position = bytePos;
            tempStr = byteToHex( byteArray.readUnsignedByte() );
            tempUInt = 0; //reset for TRUE count

            if ( tempStr == searchArray[0] )
            {
                //# tempUInt to count how many times it was true
                //# if total true's == search array length then we found match

                //trace("-------------------------------------------");

                for (var i:int = 0; i <= searchArray.length-1; i++) 
                {
                    bytePos = byteArray.position-1;

                    if ( byteToHex( byteArray[bytePos+i] ) == searchArray[i] )
                    {
                        //trace("bytes [" +bytePos+ " + " +i+ "] is : " +  byteToHex( byteArray[bytePos+i] ) );
                        //trace("search array [" +i+ "] is : " + searchArray[i] );
                        tempUInt++; //# add +1 for each matching entry for both arrays
                    }

                }

                trace("tempUInt match is : " + tempUInt + " || Expected TRUE count : " + searchArray.length );

                if ( tempUInt == searchArray.length ) 
                { 
                    tempUInt = byteArray.position - 1;
                    trace("match FOUND for search at pos : " + tempUInt); 
                    break; 
                }
                else 
                { 
                    tempUInt = int(-1); 
                    trace("match NOT found for search... current pos : " + ( byteArray.position-1) );
                }

            }

            bytePos++;

        } //# end WHILE loop

        return tempUInt;
    }

    public function byteToHex ( input:uint ) : String
    {
        tempStr = input.toString(16); 
        if(tempStr.length < 2) { tempStr = "0" + tempStr; } //# zero padding if 1 char only

        return tempStr.toUpperCase();
    }

    public function checkImageFormat ( inputBA : ByteArray ) : String
    {
        //# If you need to READ as specific Endianness of format
        //# default in AS3 is BIG ENDIAN type
        //inputBA.endian = Endian.LITTLE_ENDIAN;
        //inputBA.endian = Endian.BIG_ENDIAN;

        formatFound = false; bytePos = 0;

        while( formatFound == false) //* keep going until BREAK action
        {
            if ( formatFound == true ){ trace("## Found format..."); break; }

            inputBA.position = bytePos; //* reset positions 
            tempUInt = inputBA.readUnsignedByte(); //* READ byte = check byte value as Int
            bytePos = inputBA.position; //* update Pos to new offset move caused by READ action

            //# Check for JPG (begins xFF xD8 xFF xE0)
            if (tempUInt == 0xFF) 
            { 
                inputBA.position = bytePos-1; //* go back one byte to include FF in next check
                tempUInt = inputBA.readUnsignedInt(); //* READ 4 bytes at once (expect FF-D8-FF-E0)
                //trace ("tempUInt check : " + tempUInt);
                if (tempUInt == 0xFFD8FFE0 ) //* check IF EQUAL to expected value
                { 
                    inputBA.position += 2; //skip 2 bytes ahead to expected pos of JFIF
                    tempUInt = inputBA.readUnsignedInt(); //* now check next 4 bytes
                    if (tempUInt == 0x4A464946) //* if expected JFIF (as hex) value
                    {
                        str_Format = "jpg";
                        trace("found JPG start + JFIF header..."); formatFound = true;
                    }
                }
            } //# end Check for JPG

            //# Check for PNG (begins x89 x50 x4E x47)
            if (tempUInt == 0x89) 
            { 
                inputBA.position = bytePos-1; //* go back one byte to include 89 in next check
                tempUInt = inputBA.readUnsignedInt(); //* READ 4 bytes at once (expect 89-50-4E-47)
                //trace ("tempUInt check : " + tempUInt);
                if (tempUInt == 0x89504E47 ) //* check IF EQUAL to expected value
                { 
                    tempUInt = inputBA.readUnsignedInt(); //* now check next 4 bytes
                    if (tempUInt == 0x0D0A1A0A) //* if also expected value
                    {
                        inputBA.position += 4; //skip 4 bytes ahead to expected pos of IHDR
                        tempUInt = inputBA.readUnsignedInt(); //* now check next 4 bytes

                        if (tempUInt == 0x49484452) //* if expected IHDR (as hex) value
                        {
                            str_Format = "png";
                            trace("found PNG start + IHDR header..."); formatFound = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            } //# end Check for PNG

            //# Increment Pos for next byte value checking at top of While loop
            bytePos++;

        } //# end WHILE loop

        return str_Format;
    }

    public function bytes_toString ( ba:ByteArray ) : String
    {
        //trace("checking args : " + args);
        tempStr = "";   var str_Hex:String = ""; var len:uint = ba.length;
        ba.position = 0;

        for (var i:uint = 0; i < len; i++) 
        {
            tempStr=ba.readUnsignedByte().toString(16); 

            if(tempStr.length<2) { tempStr="0"+tempStr; } //# zero-padding if 1 char only
            str_Hex += tempStr ;
        }

        return str_Hex.toUpperCase();
    }

    public function bytes_toInt( ...args ) : int
    {
        var temp_conv_ba : ByteArray = new ByteArray();

        for (var i:uint = 0; i < args.length; i++) 
        { temp_conv_ba[i] = args[i]; }

        var int_fromBytes:int = int("0x" + bytes_toString(temp_conv_ba) );
        return int_fromBytes;
    }

} //# end class

} //# end package
```

Answer (score 4):

Both PNG and JPG have a specified header, and they're both a specific size. You need to read just the bytes for the header (being careful to check against the byte array size so you don't go out of bounds). In the case of the PNG you first check if you have 4 bytes to read, then get those first 4 bytes, comparing against that 0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47 sequence. For JPG the first 3 bytes will be 0xFF 0xD8 0xFF.

Also keep in mind that the AS3 Loader class can just take the bytes for either one and figure it out for you.

Comment: In this case these will solve the problem right at the get go. But if those sequence of bytes were in the middle of a file you are saying I would need to loop the byte array, grab each byte and if there's a match keep comparing until I either find the match or the end of the file?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. The header is a fixed size, so when you are determining whether it's a jpg or a png, you read just the header size (keeping in mind that the jpg header is a different size than that of the png header). So it doesn't matter if that byte sequence is in the middle of the file, you aren't reading that far. My comment about the end of file meant that if the header for png is 4 bytes, the file might not be a png and you only have 3 bytes to read. If the file is a png, it will always have enough bytes to read the header. I didn't mean that you have to read the whole file.

Answer (score 1):

I've put together this method but it fails to find the first value in the PNG array but the other values it finds just fine.

```
var png:Array = [0x89,0x50,0x4E,0x47];
var pngIndex:int = getIndexOfValueInByteArray(byteArray, png, 0, 4);

/**
 * Gets the position where either a single character or an array of hexidecimal values are found in a byte array
 * */
public function getIndexOfValueInByteArray(byteArray:ByteArray, value:*, startPosition:int = 0, endPosition:int = 0, endian:String = null):int {
    var byte:uint;
    var byteString:String;
    var position:int;
    var matchIndex:int;
    var searchArray:Array;
    var searchByte:int;
    var searchByteString:String;
    var found:Boolean;
    var endOfFile:Boolean;
    var endIndex:uint;
    var debug:Boolean;
    var firstByte:uint;
    var firstByteString:String;
    var startIndex:uint;
    var searchArrayLength:int;
    var compareAsString:Boolean;

    debug = true;

    if (value is String) {
        searchArray = String(value).split("");
        compareAsString = true;
    }
    else {
        searchArray = ArrayUtil.toArray(value);
    }

    if (endian) {
        byteArray.endian = endian;
    }

    if (startPosition>-1) {
        byteArray.position = startPosition;
    }

    if (searchArray && searchArray.length) {
        firstByte = searchArray[0];
        firstByteString = compareAsString ? searchArray[0] : String.fromCharCode(firstByte);
        searchArrayLength = searchArray.length;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }

    while (byteArray.bytesAvailable) {
        byte = byteArray.readByte();

        if (!compareAsString && byte==firstByte) {
            debug ? trace("Byte:0x" + byte.toString(16) + " " + String.fromCharCode(byte)):void;

            for (var j:int = 1; j < searchArrayLength; j++) {
                byte = byteArray.readByte();
                searchByte = searchArray[j];

                debug ? trace("Byte:0x" + byte.toString(16) + " " + String.fromCharCode(byte)):void;

                if (byte==searchByte) {
                    if (j==searchArrayLength-1) {
                        found = true;
                        matchIndex = byteArray.position;
                        startIndex = matchIndex - searchArrayLength;
                        endIndex = matchIndex;

                        debug ? trace("Match found at " + startIndex):void;

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (byteArray.bytesAvailable==0) {
                    endOfFile = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        else if (compareAsString && String.fromCharCode(byte)==firstByteString) {
            debug ? trace("Byte:0x" + byte.toString(16) + " " + String.fromCharCode(byte)):void;

            for (j = 1; j < searchArrayLength; j++) {
                byteString = String.fromCharCode(byteArray.readByte());
                searchByteString = searchArray[j];

                debug ? trace("Byte:0x" + byte.toString(16) + " " + searchByteString):void;

                if (byteString==searchByteString) {
                    if (j==searchArrayLength-1) {
                        found = true;
                        matchIndex = byteArray.position;
                        startIndex = matchIndex - searchArrayLength;
                        endIndex = matchIndex;

                        debug ? trace("Match found at " + startIndex):void;

                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (byteArray.bytesAvailable==0) {
                    endOfFile = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            debug ? trace("Byte:0x" + byte.toString(16) + " " + String.fromCharCode(byte)):void;
        }

        if (found || endOfFile || (endPosition!=0 && byteArray.position>endPosition)) {
            break;
        }
    }

    if (found) {
        debug?trace("Found at position " + startIndex + ". It ends at " + endIndex):0;
    }
    else {
        debug?trace("Could not find what the value you're looking for in this here byte array"):0;
        matchIndex = -1;
    }

    return matchIndex;
}

var png:Array = [0x89, 0x50, 0x4E, 0x47];
var pngIndex:int = getIndexOfValueInByteArray(byteArray, png, 0, 5);
```

The values traced out are:

```
Byte:0xffffff89
Byte:0x50
Byte:0x4e
Byte:0x47
```

If I set `byte` as `int` instead of `uint` it prints out:

```
Byte:0x-77
Byte:0x50
Byte:0x4e
Byte:0x47
```

When I use a JPEG and set `byte` as `uint` it prints out this value:

```
var jpg:Array = [0xFF, 0xD8, 0xFF];
var jpgIndex:int = getIndexOfValueInByteArray(byteArray, jpg, 0, 5);

Byte:0xffffffff
Byte:0xffffffd8
Byte:0xffffffff
Byte:0xffffffe0
```

It looks like it matches the last of values.

**UPDATE:**
I'm going to just pass in the 0xFFFFFF89 instead of 0x89. That seems to work on Mac. Don't know how or why. I updated the function to print out the hexidecimal character and string character if it translates to a string (sometimes it's empty).

Comment: _"I'm going to just pass in the 0xFFFFFF89 instead of 0x89"_ this happening because of `byteArray.readByte();` this gives SIGNED values (that is Plus / Minus signed). Use `byteArray.readUnsignedByte();` for the correct value of a byte (well, ranging from zero `0x00` up to 255 `0xFF`). With Signed bytes each one goes from decimal **-127** up to max **128**. However your `0x89` is decimal **137** so it wont fit and that causes issues (ie: those multiple `FF` push it into _minus_ zone cos it thinks that's what you want when you say `readByte()`. Phew!! Ask anything...

Comment: Is the readUnsignedByte the smallest incremental step in a byte array? What I mean is in a normal array you have array[0], array[1], array[2], etc but in byte array it seems like calling readByte() and readInt() is the difference between array.position == 1 and array.position == 4. Does that make sense? If I was to check every value in a byte array I would need the smallest step correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct that you'll check one byte at a time until potential found then just read integer from the found offset to check 4 bytes at once. A `While` loop will do this search quickly (million bytes in milisecs). Also correct about `readUnsignedbyte` as smallest increment. `Short`s put value within two bytes at once, `Integer` uses 4 bytes at a time. Hence the big jumps... Now you know AS3's dirty little secret, when we declare a var of `int` type we've just shoved 4 bytes to RAM just to hold a small number like a 2 or a 5 (really it fits in one byte, but hey we didn't make AS3 so...)