# How to get the GIF image size dimensions from byte array in AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air, gif

How to do I get the GIF image dimensions from a raw byte array?

Here is the [related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41304761/is-there-a-simple-method-to-match-an-array-of-bytes-in-an-byte-array) question. I'm trying to find if there is a string of bytes that contain the width and height.

I found [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GIF) page on the GIF format but I'm not sure how to decipher it. It looks like position 6 and position 8 contain the width and height?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think that is what you're looking for: http://www.matthewflickinger.com/lab/whatsinagif/bits_and_bytes.asp

Bytes 6-7 (0-based index) represent width and bytes 8-9 represent height. In that case:

```
var source:ByteArray;
var aHeight:int;
var aWidth:int;

source.position = 6;

aWidth  = source.readUnsignedByte();
aWidth += source.readUnsignedByte() << 8;

aHeight  = source.readUnsignedByte();
aHeight += source.readUnsignedByte() << 8;
```

Or alternatively just use [**`readShort`**](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#readShort()) for getting two-byte values (16-bits) without the bit-shifting `<<`...

```
aWidth  = source.readShort();
aHeight  = source.readShort();
```

Comment: Of course it should be actually verified first if the signature at byte 0 is a GIF one, or else return an error.

Comment: @Vesper, good point, but... The header could be correct yet the rest of data corrupted. The only way to be 100% sure is to actually Loader.loadBytes(source), and then we can just read (Loader.content as Bitmap).width and .height which probably kills the whole point for OP.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts, thanks, I forgot about unsigned, silly me.